# PHP send http response GZIP large file

Tags: php, http, httpresponse

I am trying to set up an easy MOCK http response as a PHP script.
Therefore I have this code:

```
<?php
$filename = "output.txt.gz";
$filesize = filesize($filename);
//ignore the next 3 lines
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, $filesize);
fclose($handle);
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
header("Content-Encoding: gzip");
header("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
header('Content-Length: '.$filesize);
header("location: ".$filename);
?>
```

If I'm triggering the script with small data (1mb) it works fine, but for huge content like 80mb it does not!

What is going wrong and how to solve this?

Comment: May be there is memory allocation problem , by default PHP has 128 mb memory available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not the best solution, but try to put this line at the begining of the code

```
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
```

**edit**

it seems you are having maybe timout issue,
add this line also:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

**important:** set_time_limit(0) will set the execute time to unlimited, this is not recommended but see if it solves your problem and if it does try to optimize the timeout

Comment: unfortunately that did not do the job, strangly i get back 200OK but error: getting response; null

Comment: what server are you using? nginx \ apache?

Comment: Apache 2.2.14 (IPV6 enabled) - within the SOAPUI error logs i can see this: Fri Aug 14 14:16:21 CEST 2015:ERROR:org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 71519051; received: 138

Comment: well your problem is that the file or the file object is being deleted before the download is complete, are you using S3 amazon? where's your storage?

Comment: its just a simple virtual machine. it should have more than sufficient memory. i dont really understand where you are refering to. why is it being deleted before downloading? would an increased response time get rid of the issue?

Comment: Works, greate support love it! :)

Comment: good to hear, good luck :), but please dont use time_limit(0), there are ways how to optimize it, or at least give it time like 1800 which is half hour (the argument is in seconds)